# O fragmento da wiki de tag suporta Markdown?

Tags: debate, formatação, wikis-de-tags, markdown

Tenho visto nas edições sugeridas (e algumas já aprovadas) tentativas de se aplicar Markdown nos **fragmentos** de wiki de tag. Entretanto, pelo que pude ver, eles não são exibidos como tal, de modo que a sintaxe utilizada é inserida no texto de forma literal. Exemplos:

1. Uso de ** e ** para denotar **negrito** ou * e * para denotar *itálico* (ou ainda ` e ` para `trechos de código`)

   [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [twitter-bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)
2. O uso de links na forma [texto do link](caminho do link)

   [twitter-bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) [qt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt)
3. A referência para outras tags na forma de [tag:nome da tag]

   [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) [tsql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) [diretório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diret%c3%b3rio)
4. HTML em geral (ex.: `<sub>texto</sub>`)

   [qt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt)

Até o momento tenho aprovado tais edições - já que é melhor corrigir depois que jogar a edição inteira fora - mas achei bom chamar a atenção para o fato.

Comment: Mesma experiência. Em alguns casos eu deixei passar assim, mas tenho tentando destacar de outra forma. Tem 1 caso que fiz agora, propositalmente. Ia ficar só a URL p/ colocar no principal, achei melhor deixar tudo no fragmento. Apesar que não usei markdown. O que eu tentei fazer em alguns casos que vi algo pequeno errado, foi aprovar e acertar em seguida.